# Updated matplotlib package does not work with wxPython

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I'm running into a strange compatibility problem between wxPython and matplotlib.

```
import wx
import pylab
app = wx.App(False)
app.frame = wx.Frame(None)
app.frame.Centre()
app.frame.Show()
```

With matplotlib 1.5.0 or higher, this code will not run -- it hangs with no error on:

```
app = wx.App(False)
```

If I comment out `import pylab`, it works fine.  `import matplotlib` does not cause an error, but `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` does.

With matplotlib 1.4.2, this code works fine as is, including the `pylab` import.

I've looked for possible changes here: http://matplotlib.org/1.5.0/api/api_changes.html, but nothing appears relevant.

I'm on OSX El Capitan, using wxPython 3.0.2.0.

Any ideas about what's gone wrong?

Comment: can you please report this as a bug in the mpl issue tracker?

Comment: That works for me using the matplotlib 1.5.0 stable release. Could you add some platform information to your question? What version of wxPython are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem appears to be solved in matplotlib 1.5.1.  In addition, the code above requires inclusion of the line `matplotlib.use('WXAgg')`.  This ensures that the backend is set for wxPython, not for 'Qt4Agg', which is the matplotlib default.

More discussion of the issue is here:  https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5737